# method for calling phone call screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I'm looking for method, when I want to create button and after touching it inside will appear phone calling screen, and have predefined custom phone number??

and button method to call method whit opening mailing client and predefined email address.

thx

Answer (score 1):

For phone calling, use this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:XXXXXX"]];
```

Call it in a method that gets called when the button is clicked.

For email, take a look at [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html).